# configure URL issue - module.info

Tags: uri

In my modules info file, i set a url for the configure page.

This is my info file.

```
name = Raffle
description = Enables an interface to manage and join Raffles
configure = admin/config/people/raffle

package = custom
version = 0.01
dependencies[] = hybridauth
core = 7.x
```

However, the configure option for my module leads only to

```
/admin/config/people
```

I don't know why it does this or what i'm doing wrong here. I checked other modules info files, and i'm pretty sure its not a mistake in my info file.

Yes i tried clearing the cache

Yes, i've implemented a hook_menu hook. I can browse to the URL and i get the expected result. However, it is the configure part of the info file im having trouble with.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious - you do have a `hook_menu()` implementation in your module that defines the `/admin/config/people/raffle` path?

Comment: @Clive This is OP. Just logged in, and yes i do have a hook_menu implementation. I can browse directly to the URL and i get what i expect.